# Bootstrap's dropdown with Datatables not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Can you please help me i have Bootstrap`s dropdown button to end of Datatable but when i clicked on it it is not working menu is not shown

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you initializing dorpdown in your script like 'dropdown()'?

Comment: No i just call Datatable method which create $.ajax call to database and append this html to the last column of datatable

Comment: Add data attribute to drop down in html 'data-toggle="drop down"' or use script to initialize drop down '.dropdown()' in your case better use data-attribute. Hope this helps.
You can refer Bootstap document http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage

Answer (score 12):

I added

```
$('body .dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

And works for me.

Comment: After looking for so long for the reason why DataTables and Bootstrap dropdown menu don't play along, I came across this simple and quick solution and it did the trick for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The correct formatting of a bootstrap dropdown menu according to their website is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

It also depends on the bootstrap.js file being included on your page, so make sure that you have this.

Source:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: In fact, it works right away with this recommendation, so this should be accepted answer - see fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/nbmhb44k/ deleted my own answer. It is all about `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: this works for me, the begining div dropdown class is the key.

Comment: @davidkonrad i am stuck in the same issue, i have check your fiddle but did not get what js you have add for the dropdown.